# Is it possible to edit the metadata for an MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmediaitem

I would like to make an iOS app that simplifies the process of organizing a users iTunes Library by allowing them to update metadata for their music files on the go.

Are you able to edit the metadata of files that are stored on an iPhone in the default music library or is access to this restricted by the sandbox? If you are able to do it how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.  The only thing that can modify the music library on a phone is iTunes (either the iOS version or the Mac version.)

Comment: Thanks jsd, thats what I thought but I just wanted to be sure.